# How to add a field that is a cryptographic hash of other fields?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to figure out how to add a field that is a cryptographic hash of other fields. I have:

```rust
pub struct Message {
    pub size: usize,
    pub id: MessageId,
    pub attribute: MessageAttribute,
}
```

I'd like to have something like:

```rust
pub struct Message {
    pub size: usize,
    pub id: MessageId,
    pub attribute: MessageAttribute,
    pub hash: MessageHash,
}

pub struct MessageHash(pub Vec<u8>);
```

I could create another struct and then compute the hash when setting up the struct:

```rust
pub struct HashedMessage {
    pub content: Message,
    pub hash: MessageHash,
}

pub fn message_hash(data: &Message) -> MessageHash {
    let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
    data.hash(&mut hasher);
    MessageHash(hasher.finalize().to_vec())
}

let content = Message { /* ... */ };
let hash = hash_message(msg);
let msg = HashedMessage { content, hash };
```

This method introduces another struct, and I would have to change the codebase to use the new struct in place of the old one.

Another way I is to have a `new` method that receives each member of the struct, and then output the final struct with the hash field computed over the inputs. This seems reasonable. A possible option would be to set the hash to 0 in this method and then compute the hash using `message_hash` over the `Message` struct (the first one, with hash field embedded), and then assign it.

Is there another way? What would be an idiomatic, correct way to add a hash? These are messages that will be serialized and sent over the wire, so I can't have a method that will compute the hash every time.

Comment: And how the second snippet doesn't suffice you? If you care that this hash will be serialized together with the main content, then `serde` can be told to ignore this `hash` field

Comment: Hopefully it's just for your example, but `DefaultHasher` is **not** a cryptographic hash.

Comment: Regarding *I would have to change the codebase to use the new struct in place of the old one*, I'm not sure I agree -- if the codebase doesn't need the `hash` field, you can simply write `content(&self) -> &Message` and `into_content(self) -> Message` accessors (or implement `Borrow` and `From`, if that suits your use case) and continue to use `Message` where `HashedMessage` is not needed, using the wrapper only for the parts where a hash is necessary. (If the rest of the codebase *does* need a hashed message, obviously you'd have to change it anyway.)

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, this is just an example, I was lazy to look up the name of the `Sha256Hasher` :)

Comment: @trentcl That is because of the last sentence -- the message will be sent over the wire, thus, for the methods that send/receive the message, I need to have the hash field -- I can't recompute it whenever needed.

Comment: I didn't say you should recompute the hash. I said your API should use `HashedMessage` where it is required and `Message` where it is not, and in the case where you have a `HashedMessage` but you need to use the `Message` API, just have an accessor for the inner value. Thus, you only hash the content when you wrap it, and you can keep the wrapper around for as long as you need, or unwrap it when you no longer need the hash anymore.

Comment: If the concern is about having to rename `Message`, then just call `HashedMessage` `Message` and rename what you currently call `Message` to `Content` or something.

Comment: If the hash is only used during (de)serialization, you can also use [`try_from`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#try_from) and [`into`](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#into) to wrap/unwrap the message automatically when you serialize/deserialize it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use composition like this:

```
pub struct Message {
    pub size: usize,
    pub id: MessageId,
    pub attribute: MessageAttribute,
}

pub struct Hashed<M> {
    pub hash: MessageHash,
    pub message: M,
}

impl<M> Hashed<M> {
    fn new(message: M) -> Self {
        let hash = compute_hash(&message);
        Self {
            hash,
            message,
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use either `Message` or `Hashed<Message>`.

If you have a `Hashed<Message>` but you need a `Message`, you can borrow that field. Going the other way, you'd have to create a new `Hashed<Message>` and compute the hash again.

Comment: No `Deref`? :-)

Comment: Nope. I think people throw `Deref` impls out a little too easily these days...

Comment: Although I don't think it's inappropriate here.

Comment: I do! IMO wrapper types should implement `AsRef` (or `Borrow`), but not `Deref` unless they have something pointery inside.

Comment: @trentcl I probably wouldn't suggest implementing `Borrow` in this answer because it opens a can of worms, not really relevant to the question. I'd also have to talk about implementing `Ord`, `Eq` and `Hash` correctly: the "obvious", impl of `Hash` would use the `hash` field only, for a simpler calculation, but that would be incorrect because it might not give the same result as hashing the Message (depending on which hasher was used).

Comment: `Borrow` does open a can of worms, that's true. Of course you don't *need* to implement any trait -- you could just have a bespoke `get(&self) -> &M` inherent method, and if that works I would say you don't need to get more complicated than that.